# May I ask about repo usability/general feedback?

Tags: discussion

I have written a library. It compiles. It has basic unit tests. - One could say it works.
However, I would like to improve the usability of the API and get general feedback.

Am I allowed to open a question about the library in codereview? I was not sure, being that I do not really have a concrete question on what I want to get reviewed...

Comment: Does the code and its description fit within 65535 characters? If not, it's too large to review. Reviewing parts could be an option, but considering you're asking for general feedback...

Comment: We do have the [tag:api] tag for when the subject of review is the interface, more than (or instead of) the implementation.  Depending on the language, you may be able to post the interface (e.g. C or C++ headers) alone (I recommend providing a link to implementation for those who would like to build and test the code).

Comment: @Mast I'm not sure if it would fit. Maybe... But my point is, that I do not really want feedback on how to write the code. I want feedback on the api and documentation. Like, do you see why the library is useful? Are you able to use from the examples provided? ...

Comment: @TobySpeight Do I get this right? For the api tag, it would be sufficient to explain the library, maybe an example and provide the link to the repo? EDIT: I should have read pacmaninbws answer first...

Answer (score 8):

There shouldn't be a problem with a library. Clearly state that it is a library in the title and explain what the library does in the title and in text before the code. Clearly identify the API(s) in in the text before the code. Possibly list the unit test cases before the library code. You might want to look at the help pages at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask before you post your question.

Post all the source code you want reviewed in the review and you can post a link to the repository for all the code if you want.

Comment: And don't forget to add the corresponding tag _api_ to your question.

Answer (score 8):

From the comments:

> But my point is, that **I do not really want feedback on how to write the code**. I want feedback on the api and documentation. Like, do you see why the library is useful? Are you able to use from the examples provided?

Emphasis mine.

That actually changes things. If you don't want a review of the code, what do you expect from a site called Code Review? If you're looking for opinions on user-friendliness, try a forum where soliciting for opinions is widely accepted. It doesn't fit the Q&A style of Stack Exchange, not even on Code Review where we're somewhat lenient in that regard.

Here, we can help you with how it's written and in part how to make it more user-friendly. But asking specifically about its usability smells like a design review to me. [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) *might* be able to help you with that, but it's too general for us. Too high-level. On this site, details matter. And it doesn't sound like you're interested in the details. You're not at that stage of developing your library. And that's ok. Feel free to come back once we can do something for you.